# Is the density a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, random-variables, random

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density $$f_X(x)=x^2 I_{(0,1]}(x)+\left(\frac{7}{4}-\frac{3}{4}x\right)I_{(1,7/3)}(x)$$

The density function is

$(A) \text{ right constant, but not continuous. }\\
(B) \text{ piecewise constant. }\\
(C) \text{ continuous. }\\
(D) \text{ left continuous, but not continuous.}$

Would it be correct to say that it is continuous?

I know that the density is equal to $x^2$ when $x\in (0,1]$ and it's equal to $\left(\frac{7}{4}-\frac{3}{4}x\right)I_{(1,7/3)}(x)$ when $x\in (1,7/3)$

So, the function would look like this on the interval $(0,7/3)$:

[image]

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $(0,1]$ yes

Comment: Also “right constant” is not a thing. Did you mean “right continuous?”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's what's in the textbook. I think that's what they meant most likely :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is continuous.

Polynomials are continuous.

It remains to check that

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^+}f(x)=f(1)$$ of which it is clear that it holds with value $1$.

Comment: thank you for you answer. Coulld you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234863/calculating-the-10-quantile please?