# Calculating the $10$% quantile

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X$ be a continuous random variable with density $$f_X(x)=x^2 I_{(1,1]}(x)+\left(\frac{7}{4}-\frac{3}{4}x\right)I_{(1,7/3)}(x)$$

The $0.1$ quantile to $X$ lies in the interval

$(A) (0.72,0.75].\\ (B) (0.69,0.72]. \\(C) (0.66,0.69]. \\(D) (A)-(C) false.$

I have never done such a task before, so I would love if I could get an answer how to do this or a hint.

Here's how I think it should go:

$$F(x)=0.1$$

however I am not sure how to calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first compute what is $F(1)$.

$$f(1) = \int_0^1 x^2 \, dx =\frac13$$

Hence the solution that you are looking for must be less than $1$.

This reduces the task in solving for $q$ where

$$\int_0^q x^2 \, dx=0.1$$

Give it a try to solve for  $q$.